# What is a replacement for LDAP_sort() method which is deprecated?

Tags: php, ldap

As the title says, when I try to use `ldap_sort()` method it returns `deprecated method`

Why ? Is there any equivalent ?

Also is it to possible to sort A-Z in the filter ?

Answer (score 5):

`ldap_sort` is based on a C-function that is deprecated for years by now. And as `ldap_sort` usually does not do what most people think it does we decided to also deprecate the PHP function.

Especially when the result can also be achieved with userland-code. Have a look at https://github.com/zendframework/zend-ldap/blob/master/src/Collection/DefaultIterator.php#L379-L403 to see how we solved this issue within zend-ldap. You can use *any* sort-function to get the sorting you prefer and are not bound to the sorting-algorithm that is implemented within `ldap_sort` but no one really knows how it sorts.

When you sort using your user land-function you can implement exactly the sorting you need for your special case. Sort by multiple attributes, sort case-insensitive, etc. etc.

The alternative is to use server-side sorting which

a) needs us to implement LDAP-COntrols in PHPs C-code (which isn'T finished at the moment) and 
b) needs the server to implement that

This functionality currently isn't available in PHP as we didn't (yet) manage to finish that feature. It is the better solution but as it's not necessarily available on the server you might still want to do the sorting on the client side. And when you search multiple times using paged results you will still need to sort the results by hand.

So `ldap_sort` is deprecated for reasons but it still is available. And it will be available in all the PHP 7.x branches. But you should use a different sorting-solution. We hope to be able to ship server-sided sorting in PHP 8 (No idea when that will be due though) but that might not help you as it depends on the servers capabilities.

So *fetch your results, add them to an array and implement a sort-function for that array* is the easiest thing you can do and that sorting algorithm does exactly what **you** want!

Disclaimer: [I'm the one that implemented the DEPRECATED-Warning](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/85aabd3e8593b9399db49aaeee9808454e811f80#diff-baba61601f82518312197f5420a76ae7)

Comment: Currently I already use array_multisort() (to sort on server-side) on an array where I store all names and surnames, it helps me but it takes a non-negligible execution time. I have like 3500 rows in my array. But thanks for you answer.

Comment: I know it's not perfect. But ldap_sort wouldn't have helped you there anyway. I'm not sure though whether usort (or uasort) might be faster than array_multisort but that's a different story… - sorting *that* many entries will only work using server-side sorting and that's not something that's available at this moment… We're working at it though

Comment: It should be noted that the userland implementation you reference doesn't handle UTF8 characters. If someone is looking to sort data with UTF8 you'll probably want to take a look at the Intl extension and use the [Collator class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php).

Comment: Well, I'd say that highly depends on the sorter you are injecting. I'd use usort or uasort and inject the sort-algorithm I want. Whether that's UTF-8 compatible or not is then completely up to me. And, yes I might need to check the sorting in zend-ldap . I referenced that merely as an example...

Answer (score 2):

```
$sr=ldap_search($test_ldap, $base, $filter, $attrs, 0, -1, -1, LDAP_DEREF_NEVER, [['oid' => LDAP_CONTROL_SORTREQUEST, 'value' => [['attr'=>'samaccountname']]]]);
```

will perform server side sorting

when combining this with paged search results, it looks like this:

```
$cookie = '';
do {
 $request_controls=[['oid' => LDAP_CONTROL_PAGEDRESULTS, 'value' => ['size' => 2, 'cookie' => $cookie]], ['oid' => LDAP_CONTROL_SORTREQUEST, 'value' => [['attr'=>'samaccountname']]]];
 $sr = ldap_search($ldap, $base, $filter, $attribs, 0, 0, 0, LDAP_DEREF_NEVER, $request_controls  );
 ldap_parse_result($ldap, $sr, $errcode , $matcheddn , $errmsg , $referrals, $response_controls);
 $results = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $sr);
 for ($i=0; $i<$results["count"]; $i++) {
  echo($results[$i]['samaccountname'][0]); echo('<br>');
 }
 if (isset($response_controls[LDAP_CONTROL_PAGEDRESULTS]['value']['cookie'])) {$cookie = $response_controls[LDAP_CONTROL_PAGEDRESULTS]['value']['cookie']; } else { $cookie = '';  }
} while (!empty($cookie));
```

Comment: While this causes no errors, it does not appear to result in sorted entries when used with OpenLDAP 2.5. It's possible this particular server does not support sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You can see, As Per [PHP ldap_sort Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-sort.php) :

> Sort the result of a LDAP search, returned by ldap_search().
>
> As this function sorts the returned values on the client side it is
> possible that you might not get the expected results in case you reach
> the sizelimit either of the server or defined within ldap_search().
>
> **Warning : This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.0.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.**

Also, As Per [PHP Compatibility DeprecatedFunctionsSniff Doc in Github](https://github.com/wimg/PHPCompatibility/blob/master/Sniffs/PHP/DeprecatedFunctionsSniff.php) :

```
    'ldap_sort' => array(
        '7.0' => false,
        'alternative' => null,
    ),
```

> In this testcase, it's written as `ldap_sort` will be Deprecated from PHP
> 7.0 version & It has `alternative = NULL` Means **No Alternative**

To answer your other question as

> Also is it to possible to sort A-Z in the filter ?

The LDAP protocol defined in the [RFC 2891](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2891) the `LDAP Control Extension for Server Side Sorting of Search Results`. You will have to check on the LDAP implementation you use (as it is not tagged on the question) if this control is implemented

Answer (score 1):

## Pure PHP implement

```php
// because PHP usort() cannot iterate using $array['count'], so need implement this quicksort()
function quickSort(&$array, $compare, $start, $end)
{
    $partition = function (&$array, $start, $end) use (&$partition, $compare) {
        if ($start >= $end) {
            return;
        }
        $pivot = $array[$start];
        $left = $start;
        $right = $end;
        while ($left <= $right) {
            while ($compare($array[$left], $pivot) < 0) {
                $left += 1;
            }
            while ($compare($array[$right], $pivot) > 0) {
                $right -= 1;
            }
            if ($left > $right) {
                break;
            }
            list($array[$left], $array[$right]) = [$array[$right], $array[$left]];
            $left += 1;
            $right -= 1;
        }
        $partition($array, $start, $right);
        $partition($array, $left, $end);
    };

    $partition($array, $start, $end);
}


function ldapSort(array &$entries, $key)
{
    $SORT_KEY = 'SortValue';

    $key = strtolower($key);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $entries['count']; $i++) {
        $entry = &$entries[$i];
        $attributes = array_change_key_case($entry, CASE_LOWER);

        $entry[$SORT_KEY] = isset($attributes[$key][0]) ?
            $attributes[$key][0] : null;
    }
    unset($entry);

    quickSort(
        $entries,
        function ($a, $b) use ($SORT_KEY) {
            $a = $a[$SORT_KEY];
            $b = $b[$SORT_KEY];
            if ($a == $b) {
                return 0;
            }
            return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
        },
        0, // start
        $entries['count'] - 1 // end
    );
}
```

Usage

```php
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
ldapSort($entries, 'displayname');
```

> Ref: [PHP LDAP sort](https://steelywing.github.io/note/Programming/PHP/LDAP-Sort/)